# Backbone - Difference between setting property in intiaiize using this, vs putting it on the object passed to extend

Tags: backbone.js

In backbone, what is the difference between these two pieces of code:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
  myprop : ...,
  ...
}
```

and

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.myprop = ...;
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference if your variable is a primitive type (a boolean, string or a number) since it is copied to each instance.

However if your variable is a Object/Array, then if you declare it as you have in the first example it will be copied by **reference**, meaning all instances of that view will share **one** variable (so if you modify it in any instance, it will effect all the others).

In the second example each instance will have it's own **private** variable that only it can effect.

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    hello: {say: 'hello planet'},

    initialize: function() {
        this.goodbye = {say: 'goodbye planet'};
        console.log('Hello:', this.hello.say);
        console.log('Goodbye:', this.goodbye.say);
        console.log('--------');
    }
});

var view1 = new View();
view1.hello.say = 'hello world';
view1.goodbye.say = 'goodbye world';

var view2 = new View();
```

The output will be:

```
Hello: hello planet
Goodbye: goodbye planet
--------
Hello: hello world
Goodbye: goodbye planet
--------
```

Because the first instance modifies "hello" which is shared, so it becomes "hello world". But modifying "goodbye" has no effect since it isn't shared.

http://jsfiddle.net/4rp6kpck/1/